# Replacing a cell reference inside a link Excel

Tags: excel, hyperlink

Help 
I have a link in a cell to a file on my computer called say Worksheets Aus Y8_page[37].pdf
I want to replace the the number 37 with the cell reference where I store the page number say e37. Basically want to replace 37 with e37 which stores the number 37.

I thought I could just insert cell reference and have tried single quotes, concatenation.

Can anybody help

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your file is in the "tmp" directory:

```
=HYPERLINK("C:\tmp\Worksheets Aus Y8_page["&e37&"].pdf")
```